# Unable to add comments or select an answer

Tags: support, stack-overflow, comments

This is quite annoying: I'm using Firefox 4 and I cannot see the comment button anywhere, and there is also no way to select the best answer anywhere either.

I have tried clearing my cache, and also holding shift and refreshing the page.

Update: before I posted here, I tried the same problem page in Google Chrome and the comment button was still missing. It is not there in Internet Explorer either.

I heard it was a Java problem, but I was on the Ubuntu Site and the commenting function was working fine there, so perhaps it's a Stack Overflow problem.  Again, this is quite annoying as I need to post a comment on a question I recently asked.

Comment: I still see this thing. On some of the questions I can add comment and in some I cannot.

Answer (score 3):

> this is quite annoying as I need to post a comment **on a question I recently asked**

If you

- own the question
- are logged in as the owner of the question

you should always be able to comment on it even with 1 rep per the /faq.

I suspect you are not logged in, or perhaps you are logged in as a different user?

Comment: yeah, I'm logged in as a different user, as I created an account after posting the question, that was because I couldn't see the accept or comment button even as the anonymous user. Something with clearing the cache probably finished it off.